# WARN: 10 attempts to find canonical signature

Tags: eosjs

What does this warning mean?

`WARN: 10 attempts to find canonical signature`

This is a warning as I understand from eosjs.

Answer (score 0):

how are you getting this error? can you please provide repro steps?
anyhow it seems you are using an older version of eosjs.
try use v21 and above of eosjs which contains a better canonical signature generation method than the older versions.
thanks

Comment: using the zeus command line tool, yes using eosjs, curious what the warning means